# Get document and referenced documents in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo

I'm developing a Flask app using Mongodb and Pymongo.

I have a collection in mongo called `document_load`, that has a reference to another collection called `document`, and `document` has a reference to another collection called `client`.

The thing is, I want to query a `document_load`, but I also want to get it's `document`, and it's `client` in an efficient way.

I tried this to get the `document` of a particular `document_load`:

```
db.document_load.aggregate([
    {'$lookup': {
        'from': "document",
        'localField': "document",
        'foreignField': "_id",
        'as': "document"
    }},
    {'$match': {
        '_id': ObjectId('587f6e3ef28bd63078419194')
    }}
])
```

And it works! It shows this:

```
{'document': [{'client': ObjectId('5754b202b480776b79184780'), ...some other fields}],
...some other fields}
```

It shows the `document` of the `document_load` as an array of one element for some reason, but now I'm trying to also get the client the same way, not only the id, but I have no idea how to do it, or if it's even possible.

I've been searching but I haven't found anything that can help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That sounds very relational. Have you had a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/

Comment: I read everything, and it doesn't have the answers I'm looking for. Are you indirectly suggesting I use embedded couments instead of references? This software is in production, it wouldn't be so easy to redesign, and also, those three collections are being referenced in other collections, and we need to query them individually. I'll see what I can do, but I don't think it's a good idea, and again, it was an answer to a question I'm not asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define your mongo document, with minimal structure like

```
from mongoengine import Document, 
from mongoengine import StringField, LazyReferenceField
    
class Client(Document):
    client_name = StringField(required = True, unique = True)
    ...

class DocumenT(Document):
    doc = YourDefinedField(required=True, unique= True)
    ref_client = LazyReference(Client, passthrough=False, reverse_delete_rule=3)
    ...

class Document_Load(Document):
    name = StringField(required = True, unique = True)
    ref_doc = LazyReference(DocumenT, passthrough=False, reverse_delete_rule=3)
        ...
```

you can do this:

```
Document_Load.objects(name="your_object_identifier").ref_field.fetch() 
# This will return the DocumenT asosiated by ref_doc
# This ref_doc needs to have as value the ObjectId of the reference in DocumenT
```

Since you want to reach the collection `document`, you only must to concatenate some  `ref_doc`, `ref_client` and `.fetch()`'s

```
document_ = Document_Load(name = "Payments_Definitive").ref_doc.fetch().ref_client.fetch().client_name
```